# NotFoundExeception in RouteCollection when using multiple route groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I define in `RouteServiceProvider.php` this map implementation:

```
public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    $this->app->setLocale($locale);

    $router->group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

In `app/routes.php` Ι also define a route group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function (){

//code

);
```

Now when Ι try to access to `admin/xxx` it show me this exception

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

I try to put the definition of the first route group in `routes.php` but that didn't work.

How can Ι solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The group who defined into the `RouteServiceProvider.php` comes before the group who defined into the `routes.php`

So, you should access your route like this:

```
xxx/admin
```

Comment: I give an example..Now by default url start with /Lang. If i write /lang/admin/dashboard it redirects to /lang/dashboard .instead if i write /lang/403 which isn't in a route group it is ok

Comment: The problem lies in the `auth` middleware. If the user is not authenticated, in which uri it redirectes? (probably `dashboard`)

Comment: even if i made the login through /lang/auth/login it redirects to /lang/login and it shows the error..before i add the lang prefix all goes well..it seems that the route with admin prefix is not seen..but i don't undestrand why..